# Change value of multiple cells in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that displays a list of students and their attendance each week from a mysql database.

I have x editable to edit each individual cell to set it as either present or absent.

The layout is like this :
[image]

I would like to be able to mark everyone in a column (like week 1) present without having to select each box and manually adding it in.

Comment: in week1 if you select `present` then it will change the value of  `user1` and `user2` to `Present` like this???

Comment: @milankyada No each cell is individual and only changes for that user

Comment: please elaborate what you actually want??

Comment: I have , But ill explain again . If you look at week 1 m each box under that I have to manually select present for each user. I would like a way of selecting present for every user by clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change a little bit of you UI here. You should place Check-boxes with some IDs which is relevant to the user and week combination instead of Present and absent drop-down. Now you can create a button called submit the attendance and find all the check-boxes value and accordingly can insert the values in the MySQL table.

**Just a Suggestion**: If in case you can do opposite by only checking the absent pupil/user it would be beneficial for the user as he/she needs less clicks to mark attendance.

To do that more easily you can also have a look on the example provided by Hosch Nok.